# pip error "ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '==')" when installing pandas on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Hi I just started playing with servers and I am supposed to run this simple script in python. This script however, has dependencies, ie packages, like pandas.

so i decided to do `pip install pandas == 0.14.0` but i kept getting an error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/occupy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecomm
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/occupy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/occupy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py",
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/occupy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py",
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/occupy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/occupy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/
    raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '==')

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

and i have no idea why.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no spaces   `pip install pandas==0.14.0 # <- not pandas == 0.14.0`